# Which Windows Phone 7 emulator is new?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, emulation

I just now installed Windows Phone 7 Developer tools Beta. I noticed that the icons on the emulator differ from the icons in the web site, demos, samples etc.

Mine looks like this;

[image]

But other uses a different emulator like this;

[image]

Why is that? which one is real? or latest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lower one is the "old" emulator, the one you have is the current skin, although there is a version of the tools out there for select partners and developers, which is a little more up to date, but I think it uses the same skin. There are a lot of examples which show the older version hence you're seeing it a lot.

Comment: Thanks Rougue! wonder why Microsoft promotes the "Old" skin on their website :)